# Looking for help in understanding a proof of the fixed point lemma in mathematical logic.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, fixed-point-theorems

In the fixed point lemma on page 58 of [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~dam/114L.18s/114Lnotes.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Edam/114L.18s/114Lnotes.pdf) don't the implications
in $\chi(v_1)$ and $\sigma$ need to be double implications? Is this an error in the proof?

If the proof in the above pdf is in fact correct, then I don't get the very last
line of the proof asserting that you can deduce $\sigma$ from $\varphi$.

I have the same issue with the [Wikipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma):
It seems to me that $${\displaystyle {\mathcal {B}}(z):=(\forall y)[{\mathcal {G}}_{f}(z,\,y)\Rightarrow {\mathcal {F}}(y)]}$$ needs to be
a double implication so that the deduction can be made from ${\mathcal {F}}(y),$

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there doesn’t need to be and shouldn’t be a double implication.

Reasoning in Q, if $\sigma$ is false, that means is some number $v_3$ such that $\psi(q,q,v_3)$ holds and $\varphi(v_3)$ is false. But since $\psi$ represents a function, there is only one such $v_3$, namely $\#\sigma$, so $\varphi(\#\sigma)$ is false. The contrapositive of all of this is that $\varphi(\#\sigma)\to\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I understand it now.  Wow!  What a theorem.

Comment: @Paul yes, one of the greats. Note the subtlety that this part of the proof is the one point at which *strong* representability of recursive functions is used (I.e. there’s a representing relation such that Q can prove the universally quantified statement that says the relation is functional, not just decide every instance of the relation correctly.) This is what is noted just before the conclusion in the lecture notes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @spaceisdarkgreen   I know this is a completely different subject but my next topic after I finish these notes is a proof of the independence of CH.  Do you have a preferred reference for this?  I knew a topologist from Rutgers who had fun learning it directly from Cohen's book but the account seems somewhat terse.  (For example, unique readability is completely skipped).

Comment: @PaulEpstein If you like the style of the notes you're reading, Tony Martin also has some lecture notes on forcing. They draw a lot from Kunen(1980) if I recall correctly... that book is a good choice as well. Nik Weaver's "Forcing for mathematicians" is impressively efficient. In any event, it would probably be best to understand general set theory, up to and including the proof of the consistency of GCH (e.g. Kunen (1980) ch 1,3,4,5,6) before doing forcing, and to supplement forcing with Chow and/or Easwaran's "gentle introduction" notes

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I know Tim Chow very well online from rec.games.backgammon though I've never met him personally.  He's a great guy to learn from and also knows about combinatorial game theory and other fun stuff.

Comment: On page 61 of https://www.math.ucla.edu/~dam/114L.18s/114Lnotes.pdf for the proof of Goedel's second incompleteness theorem, is it ok for the author to leave out the hypothesis that all the sentences of T are valid in the standard model of the natural numbers?  I need that hypothesis to follow the proof.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Paul Yes it is ok. That assumption is not used.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now.  The fixed point lemma guarantees that there exists a σ such that Q |= (σ ↔ ϕ(Goedel coding of sigma)).  If we replace Q by a system containing Q (such as T), we get a weaker theorem so that is ok.  Note that if T is inconsistent, the fixed point lemma is still true with T instead of Q, because anything can be deduced from an inconsistent system.  So I think we use the fixed point lemma with T instead of Q and everything goes through fine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm badly stuck again.  Suppose σ is true for the natural numbers.  Then σ is not provable within Q.  But I really don't get at all why σ remains unprovable within the larger system T.  Please could you explain this?  Thanks.

Comment: Eureka!!!  I'm sure I get it now!!  Let Q be the system in which we reason.  Then we're asking about whether there are (proofs within Q) of (sigma assuming T).  The phi statement is the statement that there is no (proof within Q) of (sigma assuming T).  It's just a straightforward application of the fixed point lemma for Q.  We don't reason within the larger system T.

Comment: @PaulEpstein Yeah I think you're on the right track there. People usually say "a proof that $T$ proves $\sigma$" rather than "a proof of ($\sigma$ assuming $T$)". (Where we're assuming $T$ is a recursively axiomatized theory in the language of arithmetic, and "$T$ proves $\sigma$" is the shorthand for the sentence $\exists y \operatorname{Prov}_T(\mathbf{\#\sigma}, y)$ where $\operatorname{Prov}_T(x, y)$ is the predicate that $y$ is a proof of $x$ using assumptions from $T,$ constructed in a sensible way relative to some sensible numbering scheme, etc.)

Comment: I think I understand Martin's notes on incompleteness really well -- the treatment is very rigorous without being pedantic or overly verbose.  As you've seen, not all his claims are clear to me, and I sometimes need a day or two to verify the assertions.  You say "Tony Martin also has some lecture notes on forcing."  This is an obvious next read but googling this turns up a complete blank.  I'm aware that his professional name is Donald (not Tony) but I really can't find these notes at all?  Thanks @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: @PaulEpstein Yeah, they were harder to find than I would have thought: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~dam/223b.1.13w/223Bnotes.pdf . I would warn, this is a 2nd semester course that jumps right into forcing, so assumes knowledge of set theory... to just quote from the course webpage: "(Prerequisites are) elementary set theory based on the first-order ZFC axioms. This includes familiarity with such concepts as transitive sets, cardinal and ordinal numbers, the rank hierarchy, and transfinite recursion."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132864/discussion-between-paul-epstein-and-spaceisdarkgreen).